# Running into an error when TryMudBlazor is run on Chrome

Tags: mudblazor

Recently TryMudBlazor seems to run into problems on Chrome when trying out the examples from the MudBlazor site.  This seems to be something that is happening more recently.  Everything works fine on Microsoft Edge.  Getting error:

*blazor.webassembly.js:1 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not resolve type with token 0100006c from typeref (expected class 'Try.UserComponents.__Main' in assembly 'Try.UserComponents, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'))
---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100006c from typeref (expected class 'Try.UserComponents.__Main' in assembly 'Try.UserComponents, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')
at TryMudBlazor.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---*

Answer (score 0):

I got a suggestion to clear browser cookies and try it again on Chrome and that seemed to have worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).